# How to publish MAXON Encoder in EPOS2 70/10 for building "nav_msgs/Odometry"

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, nav-msgs, encoder

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm learning ROS for graduating undergraduate course.

I am following this Tutorial  ' http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup '  to  make mobile robot.

I already made  teleoperation pkg  , '/cmd_vel ',  which spend the message to ' rosserial_arduino '  and

control motor with key_board button.  And next step, I want to build navigation.  So  I heard I have to make

odometry  and tf msg  ,  which need a published 'Encoder data' .

I have two MAXON motor ;  the two controllers are   EPOS2 70/10 .

I have been googling  how to publish encoder for using ' nav_msgs/Odometry '  but, I don't have idea .....

How to publish encoder data over ROS and  subscribe it on using 'nav_msgs/Odometry'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217393/how-to-publish-maxon-encoder-in-epos2-70/10-for-building-%22nav_msgs/odometry%22/) by [Ros_junior](https://answers.ros.org/users/22459/ros_junior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the feeling that you misunderstood, what odometry means.

Check out the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometry).

You don't publish the encoder data to `nav_msgs/Odometry`.
You need to compute the current cartesian velocity (and also the current position estimate based on the velocity) based on the encoder readings. For this, you'll need to create a model of your robot that let's you compute this. Typical odometry models (corresponding to the kinematics) are differential, omni-directional, tricycle.

In ROS, there exist different `base_controllers` or `base_drivers`, that actually do this. Search a bit around to see how this is done therein.
Also, have a look at [this Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros_junior](https://answers.ros.org/users/22459/ros_junior/) on 2015-09-10**:
Thanks for your answer.   actually , I have not known about odometry well just except  the way to check position.  For now.... I wonder how to get my encoder's ticks  from epos2  to compute the velocity....
I also search this pkg  ' http://wiki.ros.org/epos_hardware  '  but, I don't know how to use

**Comment by [Ros_junior](https://answers.ros.org/users/22459/ros_junior/) on 2015-09-10**:
what is 'motor_name' and how to know it   etc.....   I have tried many times .  But, I couldn't find the way to use . Can you give me an advice how to get encoder ticks from epos2

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-12**:
`motor_name` is just a namespace, where you load the respective parameters for the different motors as described further down, it seems.
So you have to load for each motor the respective set of parameters to the ROS parameter server and can then run the node to get information.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-12**:
Other than that, I cannot help as I have never used epos controllers myself.
Either ask a new question or check out the ROS wiki pages on Parameter Server etc.